# Rename column with another column's first row items and delete successive columns

Tags: r

I want if we change the column name "hits" with adver which is item in column "keyword", this process shall repeat for 100 columns or so. then delete 4 successive columns, geo,time,keyword,and group reputedly for 100 columns or so. Please note that hits,geo, time,keyword,group,category, are repeating again starting from hits,.

```
hits <- c(89, 93, 97, 86, 82, 83, 84, 76, 87, 87) 
geo <- c("ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca") 

time<- c("all","all","all","all","all","all","all","all","all","all") 
keyword<- c("adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver") 
group <- c("web","web","web","web","web","web","web","web","web","web") 
category <- c(12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12) 
subject1 <- list(hits = hits,geo = geo,time = time, keyword = keyword, group = group) 
pt_data <- data.frame(subject1, hits, geo,time, keyword, group, category, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you please add your expected output and any code you've tried?

Comment: colnames(pt_data)[seq(4,100,4)] <- pt_data[1,seq(4,100,4)],  final <- pt_data[,-(seq(4,100,5))]

Comment: @shafiQ: Please add any updates to the question body proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `grep` to find the index of the columns and then delete the columns

```
nm2 <- unlist(pt_data[1, grep("^keyword", names(pt_data))])
i1 <- grep("^hits", names(pt_data))
names(pt_data)[i1] <- nm2
i2 <- grep("^(geo|time|keyword|group)", names(pt_data))
pt_data[i2] <- NULL
```